# I can't submit or click in a input (type : submit) from a website in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I was working on a script for a chrome extension for supreme website. His function is to buy hightly demended items very quickly.

Everything work until one thing, I can't subit or click on the add to cart button. I tryed everything, click() function, submit() function, submit the `<form>` but it's didn't work.
The input (type: submit) don't have Id, just have a name and value.

That's the input form the web site :

```
<form id="cart-addf"> 
<!--Others inputs and fieldsets-->
<fieldset id="add-remove-buttons">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="ajouter" class="button" /><!--That's what I want to submit-->
    <a class="button continue" href="/shop">retour</a>
</fieldset>
```

I thought of retrieving the position of the input and simulating a click, but once again I can't get anything.

If somebody have a solution thank's !

Comment: `document.querySelector('[type="submit"]').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click",{bubbles: true, cancellable: true}));`

Comment: Well without any more info .. We can't really help .. As you can see [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lcgjqpd8/) --   The form is submitting.

Comment: Sorry if it was not very well explained, I finally found this: 'document.getElementsByClassName("button")[2].click();' Thank you